# UserControl and make Dock property ReadOnly - is this a correct way?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, user-controls

I have created a own control derived from UserControl and I wanted to make the Dock property a read only, and by trials & errors I came with something like this:

```
public partial class Header : UserControl
{
    public Header()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        base.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the DockStyle of the control
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(false)]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public new DockStyle Dock
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Dock;
        }
        private set
        {
            base.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        }
    }
}
```

is this a correct way to do this ? Simply: I want the control to always be docked to top (since it's a header :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `private set` you have is not well implemented, as it sets `base.Dock` to a hard-coded value instead of the given value. Either remove it completely or make it

```
private set
{
    base.Dock = value;
}
```

Note, however, that users of your Header class could still cast it to `UserControl` and thus set the `Dock` property.
There is no 100% way to prevent this.

Comment: I know that creating my control by code it can be set, but when creating it by drag&drop in visual studio it works.

Answer (score 0):

remove the set block and everything should work as desired:

```
public new DockStyle Dock
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Dock;
        }
    }
```